# Validation of date and month

Tags: ios, nsdate

i have a current date using NSDate which is ma start date....and i add 4 more days to the current date where i get ma endDate..

```
NSString *StrtDate= [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];

int daysToAdd = 4;
NSDate *newDate1 = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*daysToAdd];
NSString *StopDate= [dateFormatter stringFromDate:newDate1];
```

suppose the current date is todays date..thats 28th of jan the end date becomes 32nd of Jan which is invalid rite?
how do u validate the date??

Answer (score 0):

Have you run the code and checked whether the resultant date is indeed 32nd January?

The framework is intelligent enough to understand valid dates. You will get correct date.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to worry about this as the date framework knows how many days are in each month.

Comment: but i get it as 32nd bro..thats the problem!!:)

Comment: can you show the rest of your code? such as the code for your dataFormatter object, and the exact output of StrtDate and StopDate?

Comment: hey..thanks for the help..i was getting such a date when i used the "stringFromDate:tomorrow" method to get the date over here..

 NSTimeInterval secondsPerDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 4;

    NSDate *tomorrow;
    tomorrow = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval: secondsPerDay];
    NSString *StopDate= [dateFormatter stringFromDate:tomorrow];
i converted the date to string usin NSString stringwithformat method and used component separator which gave me the rite answer..:)

Comment: Glad you fixed it. Don't forget to mark up an answer if it has helped ;-)